# mongoid - Overwriting existing field warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm just starting with mongodb.
I have a rails 4.0 app using mongodb via mongoid (4.0.0)
There is a Company model and a User model. So User `belongs_to :company` and Company `has_many :users`

When I start the console and I do `Company.first` I get a company I created. When I do `Company.first.users` **the first time** I get:

`WARN -- : Overwriting existing field` for all the fields.

And then the company users as expected.

When I do it a second time then there are no warnings and just the company users.

Why is that? Is there anything wrong going on?
I have the app in Heroku and the same happens there.

Thanks.

**update 1**

This is the model

```
class Company
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :name
    field :token

    has_many :users
    has_many :feedbacks
    has_many :main_categories
    has_many :departments

end
```

**Update 2**

Actually these warning only occur with the User model

```
User.all
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.522867 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field email in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.523418 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field crypted_password in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.523662 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field salt in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.523888 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field remember_me_token in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.524129 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field remember_me_token_expires_at in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.524367 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field reset_password_token in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.524595 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field reset_password_token_expires_at in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.524834 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field reset_password_email_sent_at in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.525070 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field failed_logins_count in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.525319 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field last_login_at in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.525546 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field last_logout_at in class User.
W, [2013-10-05T21:30:34.525774 #23442]  WARN -- : Overwriting existing field last_activity_at in class User.
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>

1.9.3p327 :003 > Company.all
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {}
  class:    Company
  embedded: false>
```

**Update 3**

This is related to Sorcery so I'll check with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the warnings is that Sorcery is adding the required fields to the model automatically. So the fields that Sorcery needs to function don't need to be defined in the model. In my case this is how the model finally looks:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  field :name
  field :surname
  field :role

  belongs_to :company
end
```

This is done when using MongoDB via MongoID or MongoMapper: https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/model.rb#L57

Answer (score 5):

Is Company model extending another model? This warning is there to warn people about fields that are being overwriting in a child class. 
Also if you know that you are overwriting a field, you can pass a option `overwrite: true` , so the warning wont show up.

Comment: The Company model is just the base model. It is not extending any model. See update 1 in the original question.

Comment: How about the User model, does it extend any other class?

Comment: No, the only particular thing it does is    authenticates_with_sorcery! The other models also dont extend any other class.

Comment: As seen in the update 2 these warnings only affect the User model